# Slow query log on production?

Tags: mysql, performance, slow-log, query-performance

What are the best practices regarding the slow query log? Should it be active in production environment? If so, what would be a reasonable long query time? I know its different for every application, but on general, what would you set it in a data warehouse application with a mysql database of 15gb? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

*"I know its different for every application"*

15G is not a large data-set unless you tell me it's a single table! Your data can be contained in innodb-buffer-pool and performance should be better.

Importantly, you should make sure your queries are well written and tables are indexed correctly. (log-queries-not-using-indexes)

I'd start with 1 Sec and review the amount of queries getting logged and work on improvements. long-queyr0time is dynamic and you should be  able to play with it depending on load it generates.

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot for you answer, what about performance when the log is active? Wont the log writing affect it?

Comment: Not as much as the slow query until you fix all